# edge browser doesnt show embedded font in pdf created by pdfclown

Tags: java, pdf, microsoft-edge, pdfclown

when i create a pdf document with pdfclown 0.1.2 (java) and embed the font via

```
Font.get(pdfDocument, getResourceFile("lang/DejaVuSans.ttf"));
```

i can view the pdf just fine in multiple browsers (ie 11, ff 42, chrome 46).
but when i open the pdf in the new edge browser shipping with win10 the text doesnt show.

when i replace the font with a font family i.e.

```
new StandardType1Font(pdfDocument, StandardType1Font.FamilyEnum.Courier, false, false);
```

the edge browser has no problem showing the text.

am i missing something?

Comment: There are not many PDF viewers supporting the whole PDF format, many only support a subset. Edge is no exception.

Comment: Edge is able to show PDFs with embedded Fonts correctly (i.e. samples from http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/PDF_samples). Just the ones created by PDFClown wont show the text.

Comment: Thus, *Edge is able to show* **some** *PDFs with embedded Fonts correctly* As you neither shared the PDFs in question nor a short self-contained code&resource sample to reproduce the PDF creation, you hardly can expect more than some generic remarks...

Comment: How can I fix the PDFs that Edge cannot show correctly?

Comment: I'm also experiencing the exact same issue. This is pretty crucial since Endge is the default PDF viewer for all Windows 10 PC's. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: This simply is a bug in Edge. If you experience this issue, report an error to Microsoft.